# What are slow time events good for?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

So, sometimes during fight in Middle Earth the fight will get in slow motion. Is there something special about it? Like some R2+Square (Finisher). I've seen it for both getting an enemy stunned or getting them in downed state. Or is this slow motion the "well-timed" event that can double the Hit streak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is simply an influence gained from the Batman: Arkham series of games. The slow-motion would generally happen when you defeat the last enemy that is aware of you in a fight. It serves no purpose, but it's supposed to look cool.

However, Caragors have two separate attacks. An unblockable attack, which must be dodged, and a leap attack, which will cause the game to go into slow motion. If you have the correct skill unlocked, this leap can be countered to throw the Caragor to the floor.

Comment: Thanks! Know about the Caragors. But thought that I can do some combo finisher during "normal" slow-downs :) Will now stop wasting time with smashing buttons then.